# roscpp and latched topics

Tags: ros, roscpp, publisher, latch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I have the following problem.

One of my node just parses a file and stream reference trajectories as Path/Markers topics. These trajectories are almost never updated. Therefore I would like to use latched topics to avoid updating for nothing.

Therefore I have the following setup:

1. parse data, create publishers with latching enabled
2. publish *once* in each topic
3. spin forever

...and if I use rostopic to retrieve the topics data, nothing comes from the node.

Am I missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27513/roscpp-and-latched-topics/) by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4478 on 2012-02-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-02-13**:
Could you include your code? (or at least a minimum example that has this issue)

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2012-02-13**:
Sorry, it was an error on my side. For the record, here is what I did to switch "normal" topics to latched topics: https://github.com/laas/humanoid_walk/commit/5d02d0e81c1d49c21b6061133865462673ea6762

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to try the simpler version of the [advertise API](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a41fcdf7fd2a2bfa1c42d14d35f8f5a8e) You might be having trouble with not setting the other callbacks which you don't appear to use.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1